# Where does Websphere look for SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, websphere, keytool

I want to import a certificate into the Java truststore on websphere however I don't know where is the correct location to do so. The most obvious location to me is under

```
instance/was/INSTANCE1/java/jre/lib security
```

however i see in my Administration console that the default truststore is under

```
/instance/was/INSTANCE1/profiles/base/config/cells/nd_cellname
```

Now i've tried adding to the first location under the jre security folder but to no avail. The problem with the location under the cell name is taht the truststore is a .p12 file and my certificate is a .cer file. How can i import? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can import a certificate in Websphere in two ways:

- Using the **Admin Console** (The most preferred way):

> Go to **Security > SSL certificate and key management > Key stores and
>   certificates > CellDefaultTrustStore > Signer certificates > Add** > Set
>   the full path to certificate in File Name field).
>
> You can also retrieve the certificate directly from the remote SSL port by using the "Retrieve from Port" choice.

- Using the **iKeyman** X11 application which is in the WAS_ROOT/bin
     directory.

  [image: ss]

Comment: Thank you for bringing up ikeyman, this was the solution to a problem my team had been facing for several days, blocking a production deployment. We ran into some problems with the key store manager in the Web Sphere dashboard and needed an external tool to correct the issue. This helped a lot. I know this post is almost 10 years old, but if you still are around on this site, thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear this! Yes there are times when key mgmt from WAS Console does not show the correct view and Keyman is the Tool to use.